# Run for Same Commit in Different Branch

Tags: github-actions

When a commit is pushed to branch A, GitHub Actions workflow successfully runs for it. But when I push the same commit to branch B. Workflow doesn't run again, as it is already run for that commit in branch A, and shows a green dot.

I want the workflow to run again for the same commit, when pushed to a different branch. How to achieve this?

Comment: Where is your workflow created? It has to be on "master/main" branch and on both branches to make it work properly.

Comment: I believe what the OP means is that he would like to trigger a new workflow even if the same commit is pushed as the head of branches A and B. Github currently reuses the workflow results with the same commit SHA, so the run will not be triggered in branch B. I've also encountered this behaviour, and can only workaround by pushing an empty commit in branch B to trigger the workflows again.

Comment: @babaislove yes, that's what I am asking about.